# How to read a local json file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have seen similar questions here but I just can't understand them.

I am building a small web page and I want to read a .json file from my file system and get the object in it.

The web page is also local and the .json file is in the same folder as the .html file.

How to do that on my Ubuntu machine without using any servers and without jquery if it is possible?

Comment: Just use an `XMLHTTPRequest` http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/ and remember to use `--allow-file-access-from-files` if testing in Chrome. I can give you a code snippet if you can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: easiest way would be to make an AJAX call to the .json file. Of course, without a library like jQuery, cross-browser AJAX is a bit more tedious

Comment: @jackwanders Doesn't need to be AJAX, could just as well be synchronous.

Comment: I did that easily in jQuery with getJSON();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply append a `<script>` tag to your page, pointing the SRC to the local .js file in the same folder. You don't need to use Ajax.

Comment: Some JSON can't be referenced later because it creates an anonymous object.

Comment: It worked by just adding it as <script src="theFile.json"></script>. I wasted a lot of time on the syntax of the .json file because for some crazy reason the parser could NOT understand if the an object in the .json file was written in two lines.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's some vanilla javascript XMLHTTPRequest code, which does take into account the IE quirks of ActiveX objects:

```
var useActiveX = typeof ActiveXObject !== 'undefined';
function loadJSON(file, callback) {
    var xobj;
    if (useActiveX) {
        xobj = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); 
    } else {
        xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xobj.callback = callback;
    if (xobj.overrideMimeType) {
        xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
    }
    xobj.open('GET', file, false);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            this.callback(this);
        }
     }
     xobj.send(null);
}
```

Then you just run it by feeding it a filepath and a callback function:

```
loadJSON('filename.json', function(obj) {
    alert(obj.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Im having x origin problems with this `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/fjsadlfja/Desktop/myData/Messages.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: @DanielKobe Browsers will block the request by default because you are interacting with the local file system. Look up the --allow-file-access-from-files flag for Chrome or the security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy config option for Firefox. Be careful when using these, be sure to disable them when you're done. Alternatively, you can run a local server and use that, something like python3's http.server or a simple node file server.